# Trying to create a table with buttons to remove each row, but it only works on one row(javascript)?

Tags: javascript

This my javascript, once I click a button it removes that row but then the other buttons do nothing.

```
var removeRowBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("removeRowBtn")
var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

for(var i = 0; i < removeRowBtns.length; i++) {
removeRowBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  tableRows[i].parentNode.removeChild(tableRows[i]);
    });
}
```

Heres my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Email Address</th>
  <th>Remove</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>email</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger removeRowBtn">X</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>email</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger removeRowBtn">X</button></td>
</table>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="table.js"></script>
```

Comment: Look into javascript closures. The value of `i` through the loop doesn't propagate quite the way you think it does.The other alternative is to call the same function for each of the buttons. This function will get a reference to the button that was clicked, via the `this` keyword. From there, you walk back up the DOM tree until you get to the TR element that contains it. You then nuke that TR.

Comment: There must be a thousand questions here on exactly the same topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler executes long after the loop is finished.

Your variable `i` is always the last value of the loop. Associate the button with the table row you need to delete and use `e.target` of the event handler to get the reference to it.

For example, you can have this type of markup:

```
<tr id="r15"></tr>  <input type="button" rawLink="r15" value="Delete"></input>
```

and JS like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < removeRowBtns.length; i++) {
   removeRowBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var raw = document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute("rawLink"));
      raw.parentNode.removeChild(raw);
    });
}
```